# Change column names in a dataframe with different size

Tags: r

I have multiple file which I wanted to read into a single dataframe. So, I used the code provided on net:

```
setwd("target_dir/")

file_list <- list.files()

for (file in file_list) {

  # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
  if (!exists("dataset")) {
    dataset <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
  }

# if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
  if (exists("dataset")) {
    temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
    dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }
}
```

I got all the rows into a single dataframe. But the problem is the header is not proper. 
i.e.:
when I give

```
names(dataset)
```

It returns me:

```
[1] "Age.Gender.Impressions.Clicks.Signed_In"
```

While what I need is:

```
[1] "Age"         "Gender"      "Impressions" "Clicks"      "Signed_In"
```

Somehow the headers of the file are not properly taken into the merged dataframe. Can someone help me how to correct this?

Sample data:

```
head(data1)
```

results in

```
  Age Gender Impressions Clicks Signed_In
1  36      0           3      0         1
2  73      1           3      0         1
3  30      0           3      0         1
4  49      1           3      0         1
5  47      1          11      0         1
6  47      0          11      1         1
```

for
    head(data2)

```
  Age Gender Impressions Clicks Signed_In
1  48      1           3      0         1
2   0      0           9      1         0
3  15      1           4      0         1
4   0      0           5      0         0
5   0      0           7      1         0
6   0      0          11      0         0
```

Comment: Looks like your `data.frame` has only one column, or I am wrong? Is your file really tab-separated?

Comment: @sgibb's suggestions makes sense... might not be tab separated after all. But perhaps try: `L <- lapply(file_list, read.table, sep='\t'); library(plyr); do.call(rbind.fill, L)`.

Comment: @sgibb: firstly, thanks for the edit. No, it has five columns. But it has taken the header to be of only single column

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical, since if `dataset` is a data.frame with five columns, `names(dataset)` would return a vector of length 5.

Comment: @BrownBeast: `ncol(dataset) == 5` is really `TRUE`? Could you post the output of `str(dataset)` or `dput(dataset)`?

Comment: Consider posting three small example data sets that you want to combine, where each data set has 5 rows.  Use the exact same format as your real data if possible and try to represent the actual variation within your data sets.

Comment: @MarkMiller: added sample data for two tables. I have 31 such tables each corresponding to a day in a month

Comment: @BrownBeast they rbind together without complaint so it must be in the formatting of the datasets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, they are space separated .txt files probably

```
file_list <- list.files()

for (file in file_list) {

  # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
  if (!exists("dataset")) {
    dataset <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep=" ")
  }

# if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
  if (exists("dataset")) {
    temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep=" ")
    dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }
}
```

Or just leave out the `sep =` argument.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It was a csv file. I had to give sep=",". Sorry for the basic question and problem

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your specific problem but there is an easier way to do this:

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern=".csv")
dataset <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_list, read.csv, header=T))
```

Comment: To make this code fool-proof (matching only files with a csv extension), I'd suggest changing the pattern to `"\\.csv$"`, since `".csv"` will also match something like `notacsv.exe`.